# What kind of syntax is this in PHP?

Tags: php, syntax

```
if(true):
    echo 'good';
endif;
```

I've only see it in PHP today!

I've always been using:

```
if(true)
{
   echo 'good';
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is the [Alternative syntax for control structures](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php).

Quoting that page of the manual :

> PHP offers an alternative syntax for
>   some of its control structures;
>   namely, `if`, `while`, `for`,
>   `foreach`, and `switch`. In each case,
>   the basic form of the alternate syntax
>   is to change the opening brace to a
>   colon (`:`) and the closing brace to
>   `endif;`, `endwhile;`, `endfor;`,
>   `endforeach;`, or `endswitch;`,
>   respectively.

I don't often see it used in "pure PHP" files, but it's quite often used when PHP is mixed with HTML in the same file -- i.e. when used as a templating language.

Comment: Alternativ control structures are a nice feature but often a pain in the ass because no IDE will provide any help in navigating these structures by highlighting. At least mine doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

You can interlace the former with html very easily.

http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php

Answer (score 1):

It's exactly the same. I often use such syntax in templates - it's much more readable then (in my opinion).
Here's more: [Alternative syntax for control structures](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php)

Answer (score 0):

The PHP notation:

```
if(x=1):
  dosomething();
elseif(x=2):
  dosomethingelse();
  andanotherthing();
else:
  doesntmatcheither();
endif;
```

is also related to

```
$var=(query?true:false);
```

or in even more shorthand

```
$var=query?true:false;
```

But I personally don't like omitting the parenthesis; call me paranoid ;)

Comment: How exactly is that related to each other? It has nothing to do with the actual question.

Comment: Also, because you are using single `=`'s, `x` is set to 1 and evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

same effect, no diference and in my personal opinion the offer better readble code and clean syntax, also the end-like closing keyword might help in nested control structures, to indicate which one is closing instead of guessing from a bunch of braces.