# Meaning of this if statement [if (condition) : something; endif;]

Tags: php, joomla

I've been reading some `joomla` code today and I'm often encountering statements like the following:

```
<?php if ( intval($this->item->modified) != 0 && $this->item->params->get('show_modify_date')) : ?>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"  class="modifydate"><?php echo JText::sprintf('LAST_UPDATED2', JHTML::_('date', $this->item->modified, JText::_('DATE_FORMAT_LC2'))); ?> </td>
            </tr>
<?php endif; ?>
```

The way I read it, it seems to translate to the following syntax:

```
if (condition) :
    // do something here
endif;
```

I'm not familiar with this syntax (`:` after the `if` statement). Can anyone point me to the right place?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What kind of syntax is this in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081442/what-kind-of-syntax-is-this-in-php)

Comment: @Jeroen Google, hell yeah!. But please don't jump to conclusions. This (weird syntax) can easily be overlooked unless one's read the manual cover to cover or encountered this statement in existing code (like I did today). Try googling for `if php :` see if that throws up relevant results. Can you give me some keywords to search on so that I get the required result?

Comment: My comment has been deleted, but it was a link to a google results page of 'php endif', and the first result was definitely what you needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check this [Alternative syntax for control structures](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php):

> PHP offers an alternative syntax for some of its control structures;
>   namely, if, while, for, foreach, and switch. In each case, the basic
>   form of the alternate syntax is to change the opening brace to a colon
>   (:) and the closing brace to endif;, endwhile;, endfor;, endforeach;,
>   or endswitch;, respectively.

Comment: Giving it to you for providing a direct link.

Answer (score 3):

See PHP documentation:

**Reference**: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php

`Note: Note that elseif and else if will only be considered exactly the same when using curly brackets as in the above example. When using a colon to define your if/elseif conditions, you must not separate else if into two words, or PHP will fail with a parse error.`

The colon is simply syntactic, and is similar to the functionality of curly braces `{}`.